# How to make video player using ffmpeg and sdl for Android?

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, sdl

I want to make a video player using ffmpeg and sdl for android. I had already compiled Tutorial07.c from ffmpeg on Laptop. How compile it for Android using SDL?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

*Edit* - Over the last 6.5years, LibSDL's website changed quite a bit, so updated the link.

SDL's Wiki has an entire article on how to compile on Android, refer to it [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Android).

Comment: I have read the sdl readme but its not working.....kindly tell me what to do from the scratch to make video player using sdl and ffmpeg....

Comment: It shows ,
Missing Page

The page you were looking for couldn't be found.

Comment: Updated it with a new link